# Excel Formula to convert from cm to inches and feet & round off to two digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to convert a value from **centimeters** to **Inches and Feet.** in the following format (0' 00'') and I am using the following forumla for this

```
=INT(CONVERT(A1,"cm","ft")) & " '" &  12*(CONVERT(A1,"cm","ft")-INT(CONVERT(A1,"cm","ft"))) & """"
```

The answer is accurate but the only Problem is The value of Inches has a lot of digits after decimal points..

Please help me how can I round off the Inches part of the value to two digits after decimal point?

Please help me how can I improvise this formula
Thanks

Saram.

[See Example in the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRKxC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to use the `TEXT` function to format, and insert a space after the `'`

```
=INT(CONVERT(A1,"cm","ft")) & "' " &  TEXT(12*(CONVERT(A1,"cm","ft")-INT(CONVERT(A1,"cm","ft"))),"0.00") & """"
```

Comment: that was exect! Thanks Ron Rosenfeld. Gold Bless!